# Nuget: How do I recreate my package directory using packages.config

Tags: c#, nuget

I have installed **StructureMap** using **Nuget**.

I do not want to checkin the created **packages** directory.

How do I recreate my package directory using `packages.config`?

I tried `Update-Package` with no success (nothing happended, I only get a little delay for the first time).

My packages.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="structuremap" version="2.6.3" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this article on the NuGet website: [Using NuGet without committing packages to source control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).

The article shows how to setup NuGet to restore all required packages for a solution. This NuGet feature is called "NuGet Package Restore".

Comment: why is this updating projects that do not have a packages.config?

Comment: It modifies the csproj file to have the PackageRestore flag.  This gets set whether or not the project has any nuget references so that if you add a nuget reference to the project at a later point, you don't need to rerun the command.

Comment: it does not work :/ The StructureMap stuff is not added. Only the powertool stuff.

Comment: Have you built your application?  It runs the restore on build.

Comment: ok thank you, now it works fine. My problem now is that I have to checkin all this stuff which comes with the nugetpowertools. Any recommandations?

Comment: yes, you need to check in the .nuget folder.  This is so that the restore will work even on a computer that does not have nuget installed.  You want to do this.

Comment: Same problem here. I don't want to install binaries into Mercurial. You end up that you have to commit NuGet.exe into the source code branch. It also broke the build on TeamCity which has it's own NuGet dependency resolver. I'm not too thrilled how NuGet 1.6 is trying to restore packages. These must be something less intrusive?

Comment: @Sentient I'm sorry you don't want to follow the NuGet best practice as defined by NuGet.

Comment: the term 'NuGet' is not recognized. How can I restore all packages ?

Answer (score 3):

I know you've approved an answer but I thought I'd share what I did.

In VS2010 I went to Tool->Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console
in the Console I typed this command

```
PM> Install-Package NuGetPowerTools
```

Then I typed this

```
PM> Enable-PackageRestore
```

This put a folder called .nuget at the top level of my solution

In that folder I created a file called restore.bat with this as the content

```
cd ..
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b packages.config') do (
.nuget\nuget.exe install -o packages "%%i"
)
cd .nuget
```

running the bat file will do a full reinstall of all the stuff in your package files

To finish off the job I made a solution folder in my project called .nuget and included the bat file and other junk that was in there just so another developer getting my project doesn't have to think too hard.

Comment: This feature is part of NuGet version 1.6; it is no longer required to install the NuGetPowerTools to get this feature.

Comment: so would i still have to enable package restore and run the restore.bat?

Comment: When you enable package restore, updating the package becomes part of the build process; it adds an msbuild task to the .nuget directory and associates it with the solution build.

Comment: I tried this and I get "Failed to add import 'NuGet.targets' to myproject. What Can I do ?

Comment: @GuidoG maybe stop using answers for questions that are over 9 years old.

Answer (score 0):

Lol... surprisingly, when I replaced the package.config file into my new solution from old one, and started Package Manager Console, it automatically guessed it and gave me a button if I wanted to restore all the packages. I just clicked it and voila! It's all done. I'm using Visual Studio 2012. Hope, it helps somebody.
thanks!